# NullPointerException on ViewPager with Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

We have on our app a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with a `FragmentPagerAdapter` which contains three fragments. Two of these fragments are composed with a [Recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) for each one.

The first page (the fragment without a ViewPager) is displayed correctly. However, when the ViewPager tries to pre-load the next page (a RecyclerView), the app crashes because of a `NullPointerException` with the following log :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.findMinMaxChildLayoutPositions(RecyclerView.java:2839)
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2626)
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3011)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1626)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1000)
         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:710)
         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:724)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
         at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:907)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2186)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1920)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1106)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6018)
         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:792)
         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:596)
         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:557)
         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:778)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Here's how the ViewPager is declared :

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFrag(fragment1, "fragment1");
adapter.addFrag(fragment2, "fragment2");
adapter.addFrag(fragment3, "fragment3");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And the adapter :

```
    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

As the code from both of the RecyclerView is long and different for each page I don't really know which part is relevant so I won't give any sample. Do not hesitate to ask for a specific part if you think it can be helpful to fix the issue.

One thing that I can tell you is that if I want it to work, I have to comment the call for each of the `setAdapter` from both of the RecylerView.

**EDIT** : Here's the code for the second page.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    GridAdapter gridAdapter;

    public GridAdapter getGridAdapter() {
        return gridAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.our_layout, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        gridLayoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<Model> model = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("extra");
        if (model != null && model.size() != 0) {
            gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(model);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()){
            onResume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!getUserVisibleHint())
            return;
    }

    public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

        private int spanCount;
        private int spacingLeft;
        private int spacingRight;
        private int spacingTop;
        private int spacingBottom;
        private boolean includeEdge;

        public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacingLeft, int spacingTop, int spacingRight, int spacingBottom, boolean includeEdge) {
            this.spanCount = spanCount;
            this.spacingLeft = spacingLeft;
            this.spacingRight = spacingRight;
            this.spacingTop = spacingTop;
            this.spacingBottom = spacingBottom;
            this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
            int column = position % spanCount; // item column

            if (includeEdge) {
                outRect.left = spacingLeft - column * spacingLeft / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacingRight / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

                if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                    outRect.top = spacingTop;
                }
                outRect.bottom = spacingBottom; // item bottom
            } else {
                outRect.left = column * spacingLeft / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = spacingRight - (column + 1) * spacingRight / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
                if (position >= spanCount) {
                    outRect.top = spacingTop; // item top
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private ArrayList<Model> model;

        public GridAdapter(ArrayList<Model> offer) {
            super();
            model = offer;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false);
            final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            final Model currentOffer = model.get(position);

            holder.category.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    int width = holder.category.getWidth();
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = holder.appIcon.getLayoutParams();
                    params.width = width;
                    params.height = width;

                    holder.appIcon.setLayoutParams(params);

                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                        holder.itemView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    else
                        holder.itemView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });

            Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).
                    load(currentOffer.getApp_logo()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.appIcon);
            holder.appName.setText(currentOffer.getApp_name());
            holder.category.setText(currentOffer.getApp_category());

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String marketURL = AndroidTools.getPlayStoreURL(currentOffer.getApp_store_id(), true);

                    UITools.launchUrl(getActivity(), marketURL);

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return model.size();
        }

        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private ImageView appIcon;
            private TextView appName;
            private TextView category;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                appIcon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
                appName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_name);
                category = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_category);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: is there any recyclerView in the third fragment?
[EDITED]sorry,its there.Can you post your 2nd fragment's code

Comment: The first page is a fragment without any RecyclerView. However, yes, the second and third one are fragments composed with a RecyclerView for each one.

Comment: Can you post your `onBindViewHolder()` method of your adapter?

Comment: please post your second fragment's code

Comment: how the data appended in to the fragment is it from local or static data or else data from the server

Comment: Where's the line that you are getting error?

Comment: @Rami & Animesh Jena, please see the edit.

Comment: @dileep, the data are gathered from the server and loaded before the ViewPager is instantiated except for the images which are loaded asynchronously thanks to Picasso (as you can see from the edit that I just added)

Comment: @Skizo The log that I gave is everything that Android Studio printed. It's true that the stack trace seems incomplete. I'll have a look into that and update my answer if I find something new.

Comment: @Neeks: i think skizo means, in which line of the code points the error?

Comment: @Neeks that is null pointer because the data from the server takes time to load in to the fragment so it is throwing null pointer exception.   For solving that either you need to load the data on the activity and once data got loaded then start creating the fragment

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've got this error during one of my development. Have you checked that your RecyclerView in your XML files are correctly wrapped into another layout like a FrameLayout?

If not, it will crash only on a Viewpager and not on single fragment view.

Comment: You're right ! My layout was only composed of a RecyclerView, I didn't know that it had to be wrapped in another one. Thanks for the help !

Comment: In my case the error caused because of something different.
Check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47436165/700693

Comment: I had a random TextView inside my RecyclerView only viewable in the XML that screwed it up.

Comment: You saved my day! :-) But what do you mean by "correctly wrapped into another layout"? Is there any official documentation about this?

Comment: Why would it have to be wrapped?

Answer (score 8):

This happens when you accidentally add views directly to the `RecyclerView`. In my case, I used `View.inflate` for a decorator layout with the `RecyclerView` as the parent parameter, which automatically attaches it. `RecyclerView` iterates over any children attached to it and expects all its view children to have `ViewHolders` in the layout params, and will throw this NPE when a child's view holder is null.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you add *elements directly under `listView` or `RecyclerView`* in your **xml layout** file.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

 </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Here I have added a TextView inside RecyclerView which will throw me `onLayout error`(caused by `NullPointerException`).You shouldn't add elements directly under `RecyclerView` or `listView`.

Comment: This was the error for me. After removing child RecyclerView's elements it worked as a charm. So much as a descriptive error this `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding **no children** in the recycler view and setting `attachToRoot`, the third parameter of `inflate()` method to **`false`** while inflating the custom layout worked for me.

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.online_user, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerViewHolder(view.findViewById(R.id.onlineUserView));
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/onlineUsersView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -4):

Change:

```
 private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
 private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
```

to:

```
 // remove final keyword
 private List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
 private List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Final variable won't take any values, even if you try to add them.

Comment: Oh. Then instead of adding one by one, you can send the complete list to Adapter and add all to the list in adapter.

Comment: That is not how "final variables" work.  You can add and remove items from the list even if it's declared final.

Comment: Yeah what Scott said; a list is not the objects it holds; the categorization of those objects into a collection is what is final.
Just imagine how you would assert the fields of the items in a list were final based on a the finality of the list, and you'll see why this couldn't be done while maintaining any semblance of performance.