# NullPointerException - Attempt to invoke virtual method RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

Several developers have reported seeing the following stack trace since upgrading to Android Support 23.2.0:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2913)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1445)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.access$400(RecyclerView.java:144)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:282)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:821)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:606)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:575)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:807)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6895)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

This occurs when RecyclerView's change animation is enabled and corresponding RecyclerView.Adapter methods notifyItemInserted(), notifyItemRemoved(), etc., are called to indicate that an isolated change was made to the list managed by the adapter (as opposed to a wholesale change, as indicated by notifyDataSetChanged()).

Is this due to a bug in RecyclerView, or are we developers doing something wrong?

Comment: The reported issue has been fixed in future support library. If you come across the issue again in future support libraries, please let us know by raising a new issue with all necessary information including a sample application. If any issue persists, please report at Google issue tracker they will re-open to examine. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37078411

Comment: I could reproduce the same error with the library `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0` library. I inspected the data passed to RecyclerViewAdapter and there were duplicate IDs. Modified `getItemId(position: Int)` to produce unique IDs and it was fixed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to be due to a bug in RecyclerView, which was introduced in 23.2.0. The bug was reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199176), and I explained what I think is causing the error in [comment #5](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199176#c5) on that bug.

Here's my explanation, copied here for historical purposes and ease of reference:

> I found the source of this problem. Within
>   RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep3(), there's a for loop, "for (int i =
>   0; i < count; ++i)", where count is based on
>   mChildHelper.getChildCount(). While this iteration is occurring, the
>   collection managed by ChildHelper is modified by
>   ChildHelper.hideViewInternal(), which results in null being returned
>   from the call to mChildHelper.getChildAt() on line 3050 of
>   RecyclerView, which in turn results in null being returned from
>   getChildViewHolderInt() on the same line of code (RecyclerView:3050).
>
> Here's the chain of method calls that results in the modification that
>   breaks the integrity of the for loop:
>
> dispatchLayoutStep3() -> animateChange() -> addAnimatingView() ->
>   hide() -> hideViewInternal()
>
> When ChildHelper adds the child param to its mHiddenViews collection,
>   it violates the integrity of the for loop way up in
>   dispatchLayoutStep3().
>
> I see two workarounds for this:
>
> 1) Disable change animation in your RecyclerView
>
> 2) Downgrade to 23.1.1, where this wasn't a problem

Comment: Thanks for information, this bug seems to be fixed in 23.2.1 (at least it works for me now)

Comment: I am facing this issue in 24.2.1 version. I am trying to add scrollerview programmatically.

Comment: 25.0.0 is reprodused this error with setHasStableIds(true)

Comment: Issue is still there in 25.1.1 version.

Comment: @markproxy, I downgraded my api to 23.1.1 but still getting the issue. One year has passed. Is there any work around at the moment?

Comment: @256, the bug is marked as fixed, but the associated comment (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37078411#comment13) does not specify in which version the fix will be delivered. It was marked fixed on April 26. I would recommend disabling change animation until someone has confirmed the fix in a production release.

Comment: Still getting this problem on the version 25.4.0

Comment: Looking into the same part, they inverted the for to `for(int i = this.mChildHelper.getChildCount() - 1; i >= 0; --i)`

Comment: This happens again in 2021

Comment: @MarkMcClelland, can you please share a best way to disable change animation? Same issue in 1.2.1, very productive 5 years of google development))

Comment: I am overriding ItemAnimator for set custom animation duration, but even if I override getSupportsChangeAnimations() to always return false, animateChange function called.

Comment: @Umy - I have traditionally set itemAnimator = null on the RecyclerView itself. If you need to have an ItemAnimator on the RecyclerView, and returning false from getSupportsChangeAnimations() doesn't do the trick... is it possible that you're overriding a class like SimpleItemAnimator that has its own internal state (mSupportsChangeAnimations, in the case of SimpleItemAnimator) that also needs to be set?

Comment: @MarkMcClelland, thank you for helping, but I digging into RV source code and realize that only nullable ItemAnimator can prevent bugged for loop in dispatchLayoutStep3(): mRunSimpleAnimation flag from mState must be false. But this flag will always set to true in processAdapterUpdatesAndSetAnimationFlags() method if ItemAnimator != null and mItemsChanged flag in RV==true. Probably you have any idea how not to lose add and move animation if I set itemAnimator = null or any other workaround?

Answer (score 18):

In my case the error **caused because** I was setting a **new RecyclerView.LayoutParams into the rootview** of an item.

Then I realized that RecyclerView item views actually store their ViewHolders in a custom LayoutParams class.
So when I reset the LayoutParams ViewHolder reference is gone forever. Which causes a NullPointerException crash later.

The problem is gone after I stopped setting the RecyclerView.LayoutParams into the item rootView. :)

**So. Stop doing that in your ViewHolder:**

```
//DON'T DO THAT
RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
itemRoot.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: What's the alternative solution to hide gaps when setting visibility of the item to GONE?

Comment: Actually I would expect the item view to be disappear rather than leaving a gap, but since you asked maybe you can try this : this.itemView.getLayoutParams().height=0; or force the item to be redrawn : itemView.requestLayout();

Comment: This should be the right answer, you can change the layoutParams but make sure you are not creating a new one.

Answer (score 16):

If you absolutely need to modify layout params, you can use the default item layout params like this:

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = itemView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height=xx;
    params.width= xx;
    params.yyyy = xxx;
    itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69806347/10323334) workis fine for me

Answer (score 3):

another scenario that this crash could appear is when calling `setHasStableIds(true)` without properly implementing the `getItemId` method in the adapter

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem `RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference` when was trying to hide the gap from `RecyclerView` item with setting `LayoutParams`

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = itemView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 0;
params.width = 0;
itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and to show again

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = itemView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

use `itemView.getLayoutParams();` instead of creating new params

Answer (score 1):

I met up with this exception just now, and I fixed it by changing `framgent` to `FragmentLayout`.

My adapter used some data in fragment argument, and the using `fragment` in xml does not fill the data, so the bug occurs.

Just post this here, maybe useful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered into this issue, even with version of RecyclerView 27.1.1.
And I had the following code in my project:

```
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    SimpleItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
    itemAnimator.setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
```

And I've fixed it after removing addition of Animator to RecyclerView, i.e. this code started to look the following way:

```
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check that your **recyclerview** is not in the child's in `layout.xml`

Answer (score 1):

I had this exception as mistakenly added a nested view in the `RecyclerView`. RecyclerViews shouldn't have inner views. Removing it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This exception may be caused by a bug in your layout.xml