# android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

Hi all this occurs when I want to set some new data to my `RecyclerView`. `firsTime` it's `OK` but when I want refresh my `RecyclerView` (else section in my code) this error occurs. I understood this error will be for `RecyclerView.Animation` and see this code for that:

```
 RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = recyclerView.getItemAnimator();
  if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) {
       ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
  }
```

I put this code to my fragment `onCreateView` and Sorry, my problem was not resolved.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong? Thanks.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_distance_report_lists, container, false);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(view.getContext());
    //((SimpleItemAnimator) recyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);

    RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = recyclerView.getItemAnimator();
   if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) {
        ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(distance)) {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapterDistance(jCars, cntx));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));

    } else {

        recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapterDistance(cntx, fromDate, fromTime, toDate, toTime, distance, jCars));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
    }
    return recyclerView;
}
```

Comment: View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_distance_report_lists, container, false);
    =LayoutInflater.from(cntx).inflate(R.layout.fragment_distance_report_lists,mRecyclerViewAdapterDistance,false);   // where are you assigning this value?

Comment: @Ankita sorry "=LayoutInflater.from(cntx).inflate(R.layout.fragment_distance_report_lists,mRecyclerViewAdapterDistance,false); "  was wrong in my copy pase

Comment: Ok. Check the posted answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this way RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(view.getContext()); please add RecylerView inside your "fragment_distance_report_lists" layout try to access this way RecyclerView rv = view.findviewbyid(R.id.recyclerviewid).

Please check this example.

fragment_blank.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

BlankFragment.java

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Hope this will resolve your issue cheers!!!

Comment: in return statement you need to return view instead of recyclerview thanks

Comment: excuse me.can you tell me a exaple io this?

Answer (score 0):

Sey Layout params to the recyclerview.

```
   RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams
                                               (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            recyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

For detail description visit this link 
[NullPointerException - Attempt to invoke virtual method RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786072/nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-recyclerviewviewholder/47436165)

OR

Try to bind your recycler view using findViewById() in the activity.

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView= view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)// recycler_view is the id of RecyclerView in XML file.
```

Comment: tanck you Ankita I have already read thats duc and thats dont ansewer to me :(

Answer (score 0):

oh friends i found my mistake thats in to my send data to recyclerView thancks all to help me 
its tru for me

```
  RecyclerViewAdapterDistance_Map recyclerViewAdapterDistanceMap = new RecyclerViewAdapterDistance_Map(jCars, cntx,false);
        mrecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapterDistanceMap);    
        RecyclerViewAdapterDistance_Map recyclerViewAdapterDistanceMap2 = new RecyclerViewAdapterDistance_Map(cntx, fromDate, fromTime, toDate, toTime, distance, jCars,false);
        mrecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapterDistanceMap2);
    mrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(cntx));
```

and then in fragment

```
 FragmentActivity fragmentRow = getActivity();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = fragmentRow.getSupportFragmentManager();
                    Fragment listFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.carsList);
                    DistanceReportLists distanceReportLists = new DistanceReportLists().newInstance(jcar, cntx, edtFromDate.getText().toString(), tvFromTime.getText().toString(), edtToDate.getText().toString(), tvToTime.getText().toString(), String.valueOf(distance));
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentRow.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    if (listFragment != null) {
                        transaction.remove(listFragment);
                    }
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_list, distanceReportLists);
                    transaction.commit();
```