# Setting up RecyclerView in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm attempting to add a RecyclerView to a Fragment, but I'm running into an issue.

My code currently throws "java.lang.IllegalStateException: this must not be null" on line 44 of my code, which is:

```
layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
```

How do I properly reference my RecyclerView, so that I can initialize it with data?

```
package com.example.subshop

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_receipt.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_receipt.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_receipt.view.toppingRecyclerView

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

class ReceiptFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var toppingAdapter: ToppingAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        initRecyclerView()
        addToppingList()
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {

        toppingAdapter = ToppingAdapter()

        toppingRecyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
            adapter = toppingAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun addToppingList() {
        toppingAdapter.submitList(ReceiptFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!).sandwich.toppings)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_receipt, container, false)
        val sandwich = ReceiptFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!).sandwich

        view.sandwichAndBreadText.text = "${sandwich.name} on ${sandwich.breadName}"
        view.totalText.text = "Total: \$${sandwich.basePrice + sandwich.toppingPrice}"

        view.doneButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(ReceiptFragmentDirections.actionReceiptFragmentToWelcomeFragment())
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't reference the views before they're created. Move your `recyclerView` initialization logic to `onViewCreated()` method.

Comment: initRecyclerView() should be in onViewCreated

Answer (score 1):

Probably the Activity, which is the context, is not attached. Try to do it in

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {}
```

or

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {}
```

Also don't use non-null asserts like arguments!!

try using:

```
        requireView()
        requireActivity()
        requireArguments()
        requireContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `activity` instead of `this.context` like the following

```
  toppingRecyclerView.apply {
         layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
         adapter = toppingAdapter
  }
```

And call `initRecyclerView()` from inside `onViewCreated` instead of `onCreate` like the following

```
// populate the views now that the layout has been inflated
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

     initRecyclerView()
     addToppingList()
}
```

Comment: I now get the following error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference`

Comment: @RyanMoeller for your new issue see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786072/nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-recyclerviewviewholder

Answer (score 0):

This is how i setup my recycleView in my fragments

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        viewAdapter = MyAdapter(requireContext())

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false)
    }
```

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Setup recycler view
        recyclerView = my_recycler_view.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)

            layoutManager = viewManager

            // specify an viewAdapter (see also next example)
            adapter = viewAdapter
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
```

Use

```
layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext)
```

It will work

Also you can use like :

```
layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
```