# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to implement a recyclerview holder for adding and removing cards dynamically. But why am getting null a pointer exception while trying to add cardview to the recyclerview dynamically?

MAINACTIVITY.JAVA
This class is responsible for creating a cardview dynamically and adding the cards to the recyclerview.

```
package net.simplifiedlearning.recyclerviewexample;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SimpleItemAnimator;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button buttonScan1;
    private Button dev_but1;
    public WebView wv1;
    private Dialog add_dev;
    private View v1;
    private EditText text2;
    private EditText dev_id1;
    private EditText dev_name1;
    private TextView dev_text1;
    private CardView cardview2;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams1;
    private ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams2;
    private LinearLayout lay1;
    private LinearLayout lay2;
    private LinearLayout lay3;
    private ToggleButton sw1;
    private ToggleButton sw2;
    private ToggleButton sw3;
    private ToggleButton sw4;
    private LinearLayout ahomeLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private LinearLayout lay4;
    private LinearLayout lay6;
    private LinearLayout lay5;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams3;
    private Button sw0;
    public TextView atv;
    String ids[] = new String[100];
    String names[] = new String[100];
    String name_key[] = {"A","B","C","D","F","G","H","I","J"};
    String id_key[] = {"A","B","C","D","F","G","H","I","J"};
    public SharedPreferences mSettings2;
    int mCount,j;
    String name;
    private Context mCtx;
    //a list to store all the products
    List<Product> productList;

    RelativeLayout l1;
    //the recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    Button end;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_products,null);

        end = findViewById(R.id.button2);

        //getting the recyclerview from xml
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        //((SimpleItemAnimator) recyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);

        end.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cards();
            }
        });

        //initializing the productlist
        productList = new ArrayList<>();

        //adding some items to our list
        //productList.add(new Product(1,"sdc","sfs"));
        //creating recyclerview adapter
        ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList);

        //setting adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void cards()
    {
      /*text2 = v1.findViewById(R.id.dev_name);
        dev_id1 = v1.findViewById(R.id.dev_id);*/

        cardview2 = new CardView(getApplicationContext());
        cardview2.setFocusable(false);
        cardview2.setClickable(false);

        layoutparams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutparams1.setMargins(19, 83, 19, 0);

        lay1 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        lay1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        layoutparams2 = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 115);
        lay2 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        lay2.setLayoutParams(layoutparams2);
        lay2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        layoutparams3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        lay6 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        lay6.setWeightSum(12);
        lay6.setLayoutParams(layoutparams3);
        lay6.setPadding(10,40,0,0);
        lay6.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        cardview2.setLayoutParams(layoutparams1);
        cardview2.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2fffffff"));
        cardview2.setMinimumHeight(330);
        cardview2.setId(mCount);
        cardview2.addView(lay1);

        dev_text1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        dev_text1.setText("sdfasdf");
        dev_text1.setPadding(20, 15,0,0);
        dev_text1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 26);
        dev_text1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        dev_text1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

        sw1 = new ToggleButton(getApplicationContext());
        sw1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
        sw1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        sw1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(210, 145));

        sw2 = new ToggleButton(getApplicationContext());
        sw2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
        sw2.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        sw2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(210, 145));

        sw3 = new ToggleButton(getApplicationContext());
        sw3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
        sw3.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        sw3.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(210, 145));

        sw4 = new ToggleButton(getApplicationContext());
        sw4.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
        sw4.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        sw4.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(210, 145));

        sw0 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        sw0.setText("  X");
        sw0.setTextSize(20);
        sw0.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        sw0.setBackgroundResource(0);
        sw0.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        sw0.setPadding(0,0,0,5);
        sw0.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70));

        lay1.addView(lay2);
        lay1.addView(lay6);
        lay2.addView(dev_text1);
        lay2.addView(sw0);
        lay6.addView(sw1);
        lay6.addView(sw2);
        lay6.addView(sw3);
        lay6.addView(sw4);
        recyclerView.addView(cardview2);
    }
}
```

PRODUCTS.JAVA

```
package net.simplifiedlearning.recyclerviewexample;
public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String shortdesc;

    public Product(int id, String title, String shortdesc) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.shortdesc = shortdesc;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getShortdesc() {
        return shortdesc;
    }

}
```

PRODUCTADAPTER.JAVA
This class is having the adapter fot the recyclerview.

```
package net.simplifiedlearning.recyclerviewexample;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.Toolbar;


import java.util.List;

public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    //this context we will use to inflate the layout
    private Context mCtx;
    RelativeLayout l1;
    //we are storing all the products in a list
    private List<Product> productList;

    //getting the context and product list with constructor
    public ProductAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Product> productList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflating and returning our view holder
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_products, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //getting the product of the specified position
        Product product = productList.get(position);

        //binding the data with the viewholder views
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
        holder.textViewShortDesc.setText(product.getShortdesc());

        holder.end.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                productList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }



    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewTitle, textViewShortDesc;
        Button end;

        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            l1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            textViewShortDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShortDesc);
            end = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout_Products.Java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
                android:text="Apple MacBook Air Core i5 5th Gen - (8 GB/128 GB SSD/Mac OS Sierra)"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewShortDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textViewTitle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
                android:text="13.3 Inch, 256 GB"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewRating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textViewShortDesc"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:text="4.7"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textViewRating"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
                android:text="INR 56990"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="Button" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="net.simplifiedlearning.recyclerviewexample.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:text="ADD" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NullPointerException - Attempt to invoke virtual method RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786072/nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-recyclerviewviewholder)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're manually adding children to a `RecyclerView`:

```java
recyclerView.addView(cardview2);
```

Never manually add or remove a child from a `RecyclerView`.  It has internal bookkeeping to keep track of its children, and modifying its children will not update that bookkeeping correctly.

All children of the RecyclerView should be created and controlled by the Adapter.  If you need to add more things before an existing Adapter, use [`ConcatAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter).